# How to avoid having hidden columns on SSRS when exported to Excel?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm encountering this problem wherein some columns are hidden or skipped when I exported the report to Excel from SSRS. AS you can see on the below image attached, column G is hidden.

[image: Problem Encountered]

I have tried changing the size, use points then rounded it to the nearest decimal places. I also did use rectangles but none of these works on my end. I have attached here the expected output:

[image: Expected Columns]

Does anyone know why this happens? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Verify that you have done the following: Right click the column of the report and select  "column properties". Set initial visibility to hide

Comment: I did try it now and the G column now displays but column F is hidden https://i.imgur.com/J7AVkAn.png

Answer (score 0):

Typically this will happen if you have a table/matrix and **also** have another object (this could be a text box or another table, etc...) and the edges of each do not align.

For example, if you had a table with 5 columns, each column was 2cm wide and the left position of the table was 1cm, then each column would start at 1cm, 3cm, 5cm, 7cm and 9cm respectively.

If you have a textbox (say your report title) and this also had a left position of 1cm but was 5cm wide, the right edge of the textbox would end at 6cm for the left edge.

As this would not align with the table columns, the excel renderer would insert a blank column to fill the horizontal gap to next table column. SSRS does this to try to match visually as close to the layout as possible.

In summary, check the edges of all objects near the place where your blank column is generated, and look for edges that do not align with others.

If you are using a matrix, then you typically need to make sure any textboxes align with a column boundary once the columns have been generated, so in the example about you set the width of the textbox to 2, 4, 6 or 8cm wide and it would align with the columns.